# How to get the elements from a k means cluster in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I want to see all the elements from a k means cluster in R.

So for example I have a table named userSatisfaction with the columns: **userID,** ***variable (1 -> 7**)* and a **percentage ( 0 - 1%)** I want to find out all users in the cluster number 2.

After I am clustering the elements of the table I want to see the users which are in the same cluster.

So for example if I have 5 clusters, I would like too see all the users from cluster 2. How can I do that in R ?

Thank you.

Comment: what have you done so far

Comment: I did the clustering. So I just want to find out the users which are in a cluster, any cluster.

Comment: All objects are in exatly one of the clusters with k-means. Other than that, I'm pretty sure you are using the wrong algorithm for your data. So even when you read the k-means documentation (to discover `$cluster`), your results will still be pretty much random.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the `cluster` parameter of the returned value

For instance, clustering Anderson's iris data:

```
km <- kmeans(iris[,1:4], 3)
> km$cluster
  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [30] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2
 [59] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 [88] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 3
[117] 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 3
[146] 3 2 3 3 2
```

See `?kmeans` for more help.

So, to access the elements of cluster 1 you would do:

```
iris[km$cluster==1,]
```